# Can't Insert Multiple Item Listview into Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Im Beginner Android Developer.I need some help. When i try to insert data into 2 table order, and orderdtl. orderdtl is getting data from multiple item listview on EntryTO.java. there is no change, no error, still can't inserted.this is my Databases :

```
private static final String db_createorder = "create table  if not exists "
      + TABLE_ORDER + "("
      + ORDER_ID +" varchar(15) primary key, "
      + ORDER_DATE + " DATETIME, "
      + NOTES + " varchar(100) not null, "
      + OUTLET_ID + " varchar not null, " +
      "foreign key ("+ OUTLET_ID +") references "+TABLE_OUTLET+"("+ OUTLET_ID +"));";

private static final String db_createorderdtl = "create table  if not exists "
      + ORDER_DTL + "("
      + ORDER_ID +" varchar not null, "
      + COLUMN_ID+ " integer not null, "
      + QUANTITY + " varchar(3) not null," +
      " foreign key ("+ORDER_ID+") references "+TABLE_ORDER+"("+ORDER_ID+"),"+
      " foreign key ("+COLUMN_ID+") references "+TABLE_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID+"), "+
      "primary key  ("+ORDER_ID+"," +COLUMN_ID+ "));";
```

This is some part of my EntryTO.java's code.

```
String orderid = orderid();
String orderdate = orderdate();
String notes = edtnotes.getText().toString();
String outletid = Globals.outletid;
order = dataSource.createorder(orderid,orderdate,notes, outletid);
        for(int i = 1; i< Globals.mylist.size(); i++){
        if(Globals.mylist.size()!=0){
            Globals.mylist.set(i,map1);
            map1.get(id);
            map1.get(qty);
            }
        orderdtl = dataSource.createorderdtl(orderid, Id, qty);
```

And this is my DBDataSource.java

```
public order createorder(String orderid,String orderdate, String notes, long outletid) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_ID, orderid); 
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_DATE, orderdate); 
    values.put(DBHelper.NOTES, notes); 
    values.put(DBHelper.OUTLET_ID, outletid); 
    long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_ORDER, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ORDER,allorder,DBHelper.ORDER_ID +" = " + insertId, null,null, null, null);
    order neworder = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        neworder = cursorToorder(cursor);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return neworder;} private order cursorToorder(Cursor cursor) {
    order order = new order();
    order.setorderid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_ID)));
    order.setorderdate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_DATE)));
    order.setnotes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOTES)));
    order.setoutletid(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OUTLET_ID)));
    return order;
    }
public orderdtl createorderdtl(String orderid, String Id, String qty) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_ID, orderid);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, Id);
    values.put(DBHelper.QUANTITY, qty);

    long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.ORDER_DTL, null,
        values);

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.ORDER_DTL,
        allorderdtl, DBHelper.ORDER_ID + "=" + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);
    orderdtl neworderdtl = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        neworderdtl = cursorToorderdtl(cursor);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return neworderdtl;
  }
private orderdtl cursorToorderdtl(Cursor cursor) {
    orderdtl orderdtl = new orderdtl();
    Log.v("info", "The getString "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_ID)));
    Log.v("info", "The setLatLng "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID))+","
                                  +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.QUANTITY)));
    orderdtl.setorderid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_ID)));
    orderdtl.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
    orderdtl.setqty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.QUANTITY)));
    return orderdtl;
    }
```

Is there any problem with this code? I cant found where..please help me.. I was so stuck.Thank You.

Comment: What is the type of these fields ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, NOTES and OUTLET_ID? Paste your create database code.

Comment: @ZohraKhan, i've paste my created database code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL3 supports 5 types of datatype:

**NULL.** The value is a NULL value.

**INTEGER.** The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

**REAL.** The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

**TEXT.** The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

**BLOB.** The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Please change your create database syntax like this:

```
private static final String db_createorder = "create table  if not exists "
      + TABLE_ORDER + "("
      + ORDER_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + ORDER_DATE + " integer, "
      + NOTES + " text not null, "
      + OUTLET_ID + " integer not null, " +
      "foreign key ("+ OUTLET_ID +") references "+TABLE_OUTLET+"("+ OUTLET_ID +"));";

private static final String db_createorderdtl = "create table  if not exists "
      + ORDER_DTL + "("
      + ORDER_ID +" integer, "
      + COLUMN_ID+ " integer not null, "
      + QUANTITY + " **** not null," +
      " foreign key ("+ORDER_ID+") references "+TABLE_ORDER+"("+ORDER_ID+"),"+
      " foreign key ("+COLUMN_ID+") references "+TABLE_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID+"), "+
      "primary key  ("+ORDER_ID+"," +COLUMN_ID+ "));";
```

**** Quantity can be integer or real or text. I don't have idea about your app. So please decide according to your application

**Note:** No need to insert in ORDER_ID , It will auto increment by itself when ever there is row insertion in the database.

Check these links for more information:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_database-dates/
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: thank you, it was help me so much. I agree with you but well my app should be sent thousand order product into server, my boss was said that will be better if you record time as your primary key (it was unique and change every second),than you used autoincrement on your id. So i've try.